# CD Drive not recognized - 18.04

Tags: mount, cd-drive

Problem: CD-Drive not working / mounting. When i insert a CD, file manager does nothing. The `eject` command in the terminal does not work. I do not have much knowledge about setting up hardware in Ubuntu. Until now, everything worked fine from the beginning. It is not the first time i am working on this issue. I was never able to solve it and i guess, i messed up something while creating a mounting point?

System: Lenovo T430s, Intel i5, Ubuntu 18.04

```
    andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
[sudo] password for andi: 
  *-disk                    
       description: ATA Disk
       product: Samsung SSD 840
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 6B0Q
       serial: S14GNEACA39356R
       size: 232GiB (250GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=ad175e01
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVD-RAM UJ8B2
       vendor: MATSHITA
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: SB01
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

Tried to mount it:

```
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/
mount: /media/cdrom: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom/
mount: /media/cdrom: can't read superblock on /dev/sr0.
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo mount /dev/dvd /media/cdrom/
mount: /media/cdrom: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0/ /media/cdrom/
mount: /media/cdrom: special device /dev/sr0/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory).
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0/ /media/cdrom
mount: /media/cdrom: special device /dev/sr0/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory).
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
```

Wodim output:

```
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:/dev$ wodim --devices 
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.

andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:/dev$ wodim -checkdrive 
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Detected CD-R drive: /dev/cdrw
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'MATSHITA'
Identification : 'DVD-RAM UJ8B2   '
Revision       : 'SB01'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
wodim: Cannot load media with this drive!
wodim: Try to load media by hand.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
```

/dev directory:

```
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:/media$ cd /dev/
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:/dev$ ls
autofs           loop1               rfkill    tty37      ttyS20
block            loop10              rtc       tty38      ttyS21
bsg              loop11              rtc0      tty39      ttyS22
btrfs-control    loop12              sda       tty4       ttyS23
bus              loop13              sda1      tty40      ttyS24
cdrom            loop14              sg0       tty41      ttyS25
cdrw             loop15              sg1       tty42      ttyS26
char             loop16              shm       tty43      ttyS27
console          loop17              snapshot  tty44      ttyS28
core             loop18              snd       tty45      ttyS29
cpu              loop19              sr0       tty46      ttyS3
cpu_dma_latency  loop2               stderr    tty47      ttyS30
cuse             loop20              stdin     tty48      ttyS31
disk             loop21              stdout    tty49      ttyS4
dm-0             loop22              tpm0      tty5       ttyS5
dm-1             loop23              tty       tty50      ttyS6
dri              loop24              tty0      tty51      ttyS7
drm_dp_aux0      loop25              tty1      tty52      ttyS8
drm_dp_aux1      loop26              tty10     tty53      ttyS9
drm_dp_aux2      loop27              tty11     tty54      ubuntu-vg
dvd              loop3               tty12     tty55      uhid
dvdrw            loop4               tty13     tty56      uinput
ecryptfs         loop5               tty14     tty57      urandom
fb0              loop6               tty15     tty58      userio
fd               loop7               tty16     tty59      v4l
full             loop8               tty17     tty6       vcs
fuse             loop9               tty18     tty60      vcs1
hpet             loop-control        tty19     tty61      vcs2
hugepages        mapper              tty2      tty62      vcs3
hwrng            mcelog              tty20     tty63      vcs4
i2c-0            media0              tty21     tty7       vcs5
i2c-1            mei0                tty22     tty8       vcs6
i2c-2            mem                 tty23     tty9       vcsa
i2c-3            memory_bandwidth    tty24     ttyprintk  vcsa1
i2c-4            mqueue              tty25     ttyS0      vcsa2
i2c-5            net                 tty26     ttyS1      vcsa3
i2c-6            network_latency     tty27     ttyS10     vcsa4
i2c-7            network_throughput  tty28     ttyS11     vcsa5
i2c-8            null                tty29     ttyS12     vcsa6
i2c-9            nvram               tty3      ttyS13     vfio
initctl          port                tty30     ttyS14     vga_arbiter
input            ppp                 tty31     ttyS15     vhci
kmsg             psaux               tty32     ttyS16     vhost-net
kvm              ptmx                tty33     ttyS17     vhost-vsock
lightnvm         ptp0                tty34     ttyS18     video0
log              pts                 tty35     ttyS19     zero
loop0            random              tty36     ttyS2
```

Further output:

```
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:/dev$ lsmod | grep sr_mod
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:/dev$ lsmod | grep sg
andi@andi-ThinkPad-T430s:/dev$ ls -l /dev/sr0 
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Dez 30 14:21 /dev/sr0
```

Appreciate your help and wish you all a happy new year :)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Audio CDs are not recognised on my 18.04 setup. Even when I open VLC media player and manually direct it to play, I just get errors.